# How to append input element in AJAX request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to append the authenticity token in my partial from `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` 
which lives in application.html.erb through AJAX request.

```
#_settings.html.erb
<form id="settings" method="post" action="/settings/save">
  #The input element should go here
</form>
```

And here's something I tried to do in AJAX request js file:

```
function settings(){
      var AUTH_TOKEN = jQuery('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

      form = jQuery('<form/>');
      form.attr('method', 'post');

      form.append(jQuery('<input>').attr({
          type: 'hidden',
          id: 'authenticity_token',
          name: 'authenticity_token',
          value: AUTH_TOKEN
      }));
      form.submit();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/settings/save',
            success: ...
```

In any case, when inspect element I do not have ***input*** element inside my form. What am I missing?

Comment: You can tell rails to render the form tag already with an auth token if you use form_tag/form/with helpers. Just add `authenticity_token: true` as an option. That way you don't need to copy the token. If you  really really need that, check how jquery_ujs does it https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L215

Comment: it generates a different token from `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`. I need exactly same